# Domain repository for requirements management - build or buy?

Tags: dns

In my organisation, we have some very inefficient processes around managing requirements, tracking what was actually delivered on what versions, etc, do subsequent releases break previous functionality, etc - its currently all managed manually. The requirements are spread over several documents and issue trackers, and the implementation details is in code in subversion, Jira, TestLink. I'm trying to put together a system that consolidates the requirements info, so that it is sourced from a single, authoritative source, is accessible via standard interfaces - web services, browsers, etc, and can be automatically validated against. The actual domain knowledge is not that complicated but is highly proprietary and non-standard (i.e., not just customers with addresses, emails, etc), and is relational: customers have certain functionalities, features switched on/off, specific datasources hooked up - all on specific versions. So modelling this should be straightforward.

Can anyone advise the best approach for this - I a certain that I can develop a system from scratch that matches exactly the requirements, in say ruby on rails, grails, or some RAD framework. But I'm having difficulty getting management buy-in, they would feel safer with an off the shelf solution.

Can anyone recommend such a system? Or am I better off building it from scratch, as I feel I am? I'm afraid a bought system would take just as long to deploy, and would not meet our requirements.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you are describing two different problems.  The first is getting everyone to standardize and the second is selecting a good tool for requirements management.  I wouldn't worry so much about the tool as I would the process and the people.  Having the best tool in the world won't help if your various project managers don't want to share.

So, my suggestion is to start simple.  Grab [Redmine](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) or [Trac](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac) and take on the challenge of getting everyone to standardize.  Once you have everyone in the right mindset then you can improve the tools you use for storage.

Answer (score 1):

{disclaimer - mentioning my employer's product}

The brief experiments I made with a commercial tool [RequisitePro](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/awdtools/reqpro/) seemed pretty good me. Allowed one to annotate existing Word docs and create a real-time linked database of the identified requisistes then perform lots of analysis and tracking of them.

Sometimes when I see a commercial product I think "Oh, well nice glossy bits but the fundamentals I could knock up in Perl in a weekend." That's not the case with this stuff. I would certainly look at commercial products in this space and exeperiment with a couple (ReqPro has a free trial, I guess the competition will too) before spending time on my own development.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a mill for the reply. I will take a look at RequisitePro, at least I'll be following the "Nobody ever got fired for buying IBM" strategy ;) youre right, and I kinda knew it, in these situations, buy is better. It is tempting when I can visualise throwing it together quickly, but theres other tradeoffs and risks with that approach.

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: I know a guy who got fired for buying IBM a few decades ago.

Answer (score 0):

While Requisite Pro enforces a standard and that can certainly help you in your task, I'd certainly second Mark on trying to standardize the input by agreement with personnel and using a more flexible tool like Trac, Redmine (which both have incredibly fast deploy and setup times, especially if you host them from a VM) or even a custom one if you can get the management to endorse your project.